# Dialogs are showing at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I am showing the dialogs at this way in all the views:

```
<f:view locale="#{loginBB.localeCode}">
    <ui:insert name="dialogs" />
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" redisplay="false" />
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</f:view>
```

But they are showing at the bottom of the page

I have made this changes in all dialogs using CSS:

```
/* Put the dialogs on the top of the screen. It only works on firefox */
.ui-dialog {
    position: absolute;
}

/* Disable scroll on the loading dialog */
.disable-scroll .ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}
```

[image]

What they are not showing at the top of the screen?

**Edit:**
I removed the CSS styles but dialogs still appearing at the bottom of the page in iPads. Tomorrow I will test this in safari from Mac OS X

**This is my styles.css file:**

```
td.right {
    text-align: right;
}

td.center {
    text-align: center;
}

table td,table tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data tr,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data-empty tr,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data td,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data-empty td
    {
    border-color: #C1DFFA;
}

.odd-row {
    background: #ECF5FE;
}

.ui-panelgrid tr,.ui-panelgrid td {
    border: none;
}

.ui-panelgrid td {
    padding: 2px;
}

.panelgrid-center {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.ui-inputfield.uppercased {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ui-inputfield {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ui-inputfield.no-uppercased {
    text-transform: none;
}

.ui-selectonemenu {
    width: 144px !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-label {
    font-size: 95%;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list-item {
    font-size: 95%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.ui-inputtext {
    width: 137px !important;
}

.ui-widget {
    font-size: 70%;
}

.ui-panel {
    float: left;
}

.ui-outputlabel-rfi {
    color: red;
}

.ui-outputlabel {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-menubar {
    background: #C1DFFA;
}

.ui-panel .ui-panel-content {
    padding: 0;
}

.ui-datatable thead th,.ui-datatable tbody td,.ui-datatable tfoot td {
    padding: 2px;
}

.justify-text {
    text-align: justify !important;
}

.negative-number {
    color: red;
}

.small-icon {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.small-inputtext {
    width: 80px !important;
}

.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**My template file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="#{resource['images:favicon.ico']}" rel="shortcut icon"
            type="image/x-icon" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $("div[role='tabpanel']").attr("aria-hidden", "false").attr(
                            "style", "display: block");
                    $("h3[role='tab']").removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass(
                            "ui-corner-top ui-state-active").find("span").attr(
                            "class", "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
                });
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <o:importConstants type=" ... Constants 1 ... " />
        <o:importConstants type=" ... Constants 2 ... " />
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />

                ...

        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    ... Here is located the application menu ...
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:view locale="#{loginBB.localeCode}">
                        <ui:insert name="dialogs" />
                        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" redisplay="false" />
                        <ui:insert name="bodyContent" />
                    </f:view>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**Example of view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="bodyContent">
        ... Body components ...
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="dialogs">
        <p:dialog closeOnEscape="true"
            header="Find products" id="products"
            modal="true" position="top" widgetVar="productsWV">
            <h:form id="productsForm">
                <p:focus for="productName" />
                <pe:keyFilter for="code" mask="pint" />
                <pe:keyFilter for="productName" mask="alpha" />
                <f:view locale="#{loginBB.localeCode}">
                    <p:messages closable="true" />
                </f:view>
                <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                    ... Dialog components ...
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Chrome is reserving the space of dialogs before the view content:**
[image]

**Last Edit (Error found)**

After adding the `styles.css` file I have the following peace of code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:ajaxStatus onerror="loadingDLG.hide(); ajaxErrorDLG.show()"
        onstart="loadingDialog.show()" onsuccess="loadingDLG.hide()">
    </p:ajaxStatus>
    <p:dialog closable="false" draggable="false" modal="true"
        resizable="false" showHeader="false" styleClass="disable-scroll"
        widgetVar="loadingDialog">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:loading.gif']}" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

If I remove it from the template, the views and the dialogs are shown perfectly. I don't know how to put it in the template because I need it

Comment: What if you undo/remove those CSS changes? Do the dialogs then position as intented? If so, why exactly did you made those CSS changes then? Perhaps the problem which you intented to solve with this CSS has to be solved differently. You'd better reframe the question accordingly to concentrate on that problem instead of on a side effect of a possible solution to a different problem.

Comment: I edited my question putting the reason why I made those CSS changes. And it show the dialogs on the top of the screen only in firefox. In the other browsers it show the dialog on the bottom of the page

Comment: Without that CSS it works for me in all browsers. Perhaps there's more into your code? Try posting an SSCCE.

Comment: @BalusC apparently after I apply the changes that you suggest me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643367/dont-redisplay-messages-already-shown-in-dialog-in-pmessages-autoupdate-true and removing the CSS mentioned in this question, the problem was fixed. Thanks

Comment: @BalusC Do you need to answer this question to accept your answer?

Comment: @BalusC I have the same problem in safari on iPads and Mac OS X. Dialogs appear at the bottom of the page

Comment: If you remove your CSS and use my CSS in the other answer (without `appendToBody=true`) then it should theoretically work just fine on Mac as well (haven't tried that as I don't have Apple things near me at this moment). Didn't you forgot to remove the `appendToBody=true`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I remove appendToBody="true" and all is right. Thanks @BalusC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implemented your dialog composition that way based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23089463) on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643367) about preventing the `<p:messages>` from redisplaying the dialog's messages in the background. That answer assumed that you didn't made any changes to the default PrimeFaces CSS with regard to dialogs. You should in fact **remove** any custom `.ui-dialog*` selectors in order to get the dialogs to work as intented based on the answer. You should also **not** have the need for `appendToBody="true"` as mentioned in the comments of the answer.

As to the problem symptoms you observed; dialogs have in CSS a default `position` value of `fixed`, meaning that it's positioned relative to the viewport (the browser's visible area). In other words, it doesn't scroll along with the page when you scroll with the page. The dialog just stays there ... *fixed*. When you change the `position` to `absolute`, then it would be positioned relative to the HTML document itself. So, after opening the dialog, the dialog will scroll along with the page when you scroll the page. It'll stick at exactly that position as it was at the moment you opened the dialog. So if the page was scrolled down at that moment, the dialog will also stay down all the time.

Further, PrimeFaces runs also some JavaScript code when the dialog is opened in order to properly center the dialog in the viewport and if necessary also auto-size it. You can see it by the `style` attribute being set with fixed CSS `left` and `top` properties. The JavaScript calculates that based on the viewport. However, that calculation apparently failed in Safari when you set `appendToBody="true"` and they were somehow calculated relative to the bottom of the HTML document.

Comment: I still having problems with safari and chrome in iPad and safari in Mac OS X.

Comment: Please show an SSCCE. There's apparently more into your code causing this problem which is not visible in the information provided so far. I also asked for this in the comment of the previous question.

Comment: You have the `<ui:insert>` for dialogs (and the `<f:view>`) inside a `<p:panelGrid>`? This is quite unexpected. Now all the panel grid CSS applies on the dialog as well. You should move that `<ui:insert>` outside the `<p:panelGrid>`, as direct child of `<h:body>`.

Comment: I use a panelGrid to organize my view (the position of the menu at left and the position of the components at right)

Comment: Yes, I understand that part, but the dialogs shouldn't end up in there at all. They should be an immediate child of `<h:body>`. Move that `<ui:insert>` for dialogs outside (and if applicable wrt locale and such, merge the nested `<f:view>` with the top level `<f:view>` which you already have there).

Comment: Ok, it seems your suggests fix my problem. I will deploy my application later and after I test it in all platforms I'll tell you what happened

Comment: I get Dialogs in the right position but the main view appears at the bottom of the page. Firefox works very well, the other browsers reserve a blank space for dialogs and then put the main view

Comment: Doing many tests I see that the problem happens when I click a p:menuitem from the p:panelMenu. If I put the url of each view directly in the browser the problem doesn't appear

Comment: So you're navigating by post/ajax instead of get?

Comment: I am navigating by post/ajax. The error is really shown at the bottom of my question. The real problem is a conflict with p:ajaxStatus component and its corresponding p:dialog component. If I remove that lines, dialogs load perfectly

Comment: This is a great step in the right direction. You've now been able to pinpoint the real cause of the problem while trying to create a true SSCCE (please try to do this in your future questions as well, it saves yourself and us from wasting time because you didn't provide all the necessary information). Before looking into this, can you please tell the exact PrimeFaces version used?

Comment: Excellent @BalusC I will do that. The PrimeFaces version is 4.0

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it. Can you please edit your question to include the SSCCE? I have to make way too much edits on the code snippets provided so far in order to get it to run (removing irrelevant clutter, fixing runtime errors, stubbing data, etc). If you're still unsure about the SSCCE, check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for hints. Anyone on the world (including yourself) must be able to reproduce your problem by just copypasting the provided code unmodified (expect of "the obvious") into a blank environment with everything set to default (unless otherwise specified).